# Why Google Chrome is reserving Terabytes scale virtual memory?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chrome, htop

My system was running slow recently and I checked `htop` to identify resource consumption. `RES` Column is `213M` which is quite normal for chrome. I was surprised after looking at `VIRT` column, Google Chrome was taking `1.1T` !!!

I killed chrome and open again and still it was using `1.1T` VIRT memory. Any pointer would be helpful if Higher `VIRT` is not normal and need to be fixed.

Laptop Hardware details.

```
Processor Intel® Core™ i3-4005U CPU @ 1.70GHz × 4 
Graphics NVD7 / Intel® HD Graphics 4400 (HSW GT2)
Memory 7.7 GiB
Disk Capacity 740.2 GB
```

```
// uname -srvmpio
Linux 5.13.0-41-generic #46~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 20 13:16:21 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
// Google Chrome version
Version 102.0.5005.61 (Official Build) (64-bit)
```

[image: Google Chrome taking 1.1T Virtual Memory]

Comment: I also just noticed this... I think this must be the result of some recent change in Chrome since I'm sure that I would have noticed if this had been like this for some time. In my case, I basically took Artem's advice and switched the "Virtual Memory" column in System Monitor to "Memory" instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please disregard `VIRT`. I've never used or seen anyone use or pay attention to it ever.

It basically means nothing. No idea why `top`/`htop` still show it.

Mugurel Sumanariu once wrote [about it](https://Mugurel%20Sumanariu):

> `VIRT` stands for the virtual size of a process, which is the sum of memory it is actually using, memory it has mapped into itself (for instance the video card’s RAM for the X server), files on disk that have been mapped into it (most notably shared libraries), and memory shared with other processes. VIRT represents how much memory the program is able to access at the present moment.

(On a system where memory overcommit is disabled it could mean something but you wouldn't want to use such a system).

Comment: I think VIRT is used to represent how much virtual memory program is using. Operating system uses technique called pagination. That allows bigger programs to be run without loading whole program at once in memory. I am not sure if same is going here or not.

Comment: "I think VIRT is used to represent how much virtual memory program is using", nope, you think wrong.

*VIRT stands for the virtual size of a process, which is the sum of memory it is actually using, memory it has mapped into itself (for instance the video card’s RAM for the X server), files on disk that have been mapped into it (most notably shared libraries), and memory shared with other processes. VIRT represents how much memory the program is **able to access** at the present moment*. Again, no one in the world of Linux uses or pays attention to this data.

Comment: Overcommit has a place in certain environments. I personally have not used it since my Irix days with large chemical datasets but it was essential then to keep forks from failing with not enough memory.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov, "VIRT represents how much memory the program is able to access at the present moment." I am not sure why Chrome is using 1.1T Memory. Thank you.

Comment: It's not actually using that much RAM. :-) You cannot use more than you physically can.

Comment: Chrome is a special snowflake and doesn't follow the normal conventions of literally every other single user desktop program.  Why?  Don't ask such questions, apparently.

Comment: Check your virtual memory usage with `free` or `swapon`. Right now, I see 0 Bytes are used on my system, yet top/htop show numerous processes, including top, systemd... filling the VIRT column. This is not a chrome issue, really.

Comment: @yellowdolphin I suppose when you say “virtual memory” you mean _memory paged out to disk_ – but the VIRT column does _not_ mean that at all (read this answer you commented on to see what it means instead)

Answer (score 12):

This is because of a Chrome security feature called Caged Pointers. The idea is you put all Javascript objects inside this huge virtual address space, and all browser private stuff outside it, and then you can easily detect if someone tries to break out of the Javascript sandbox.

See https://docs.google.com/document/d/1HSap8-J3HcrZvT7-5NsbYWcjfc0BVoops5TDHZNsnko/edit

Comment: this is the actual answer